# Variance, Covariance, Autocovariance

Tags: time-series, variance, covariance

could anyone explain the differences between the Variance, Covariance and Autocovariance, please?

The general topic is time series analysis - ARIMA models + vector models (VAR)

Comment: If you read about each of them separately and then compare them as far as you have understood them, do you not see any differences?

Comment: From what I understood, covariance is the same as autocovariance. Variance is the "spread" of one variable. Not sure about covariance. Looks to me like a correlation of two variables.